# What is the preferred way to identify whether a stored procedure exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've historically used the following as part of a stored procedure deployment script:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects O 
   WHERE O.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SPROC_NAME]') 
   AND OBJECTPROPERTY(O.[object_id],N'IsProcedure') = 1)

    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPROC_NAME] AS')
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPROC_NAME]
AS
BEGIN ...
```

I did not know about the overload to `OBJECT_ID` which takes a type for object ID lookup, for example:

```
OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SPROC_NAME]', N'P')
```

It seems like using that overload would make the `OBJECTPROPERTY` lookup unnecessary.

I'd like to know if there is any downside to using just the `OBJECT_ID` overload and dropping the `OBJECTPROPERTY` lookup.

Comment: SQL Objects all share the same unique namespace. `OBJECT_ID` returns the ID of an object with that name, if it exists. `OBJECTPROPERTY` confirms that the object is actually a Stored Procedure, because there could be a Table or View named `[SPROC_NAME]` (and if there is, you won't be able to create a sproc with that name either).

Comment: If the second parameter is specified, `OBJECT_ID` will only return a not-null value if an object of that type exists. (Be sure to specify schema, dunno what happens if it's a table in one schema and a procedure in another...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer this form, and have stopped using the `OBJECT*` metadata functions as much as possible, since [they can block even at loose isolation levels](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/432497/metadata-functions-should-follow-same-isolation-semantics-as-metadata-queries):

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT 1 FROM sys.procedures AS p
     INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
     ON p.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
     WHERE p.name = N'Procedure_Name' AND s.name = N'dbo'
)
BEGIN
  EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure_Name AS';
END
```

Comment: +1. I tend to drop if they already exist and then re-create, just to make sure I always get the latest version...

Comment: @Mitch the CREATE stub allows the real body to always be an ALTER, even if the procedure doesn't exist yet, so that it doesn't all have to be dynamic SQL.

Comment: I've also used DROP and CREATE scripts previously, but as someone recently pointed out to me, this affects the create_date associated with that procedure. Not an issue if you aren't concerned with this historical info/metadata, but something to be aware of at least.

Comment: Interesting; I like this!  I didn't know about the blocking issue.  DROP/CREATE also loses security settings (if you're not including them as part of the script).

Answer (score 1):

Your condition can be a bit shorter:

```
    IF OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Procedure_Name', 'P')) IS NULL
    BEGIN
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql 'CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure_Name AS'
    END
```

Another way:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Procedure_Name', 'P') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql 'CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure_Name AS'
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

My prefered way is :

```
  if object_id('x') is not null
  begin
    drop procedure x
  end
  go
  create procedure x ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

my $.02 -

Use the object_id method with the 2nd parameter.  It makes the code easier to read.

Comment: `sys.objects` is neither a system table nor a backward compatibility view. It is a catalog view and I think it's quite subjective whether `OBJECT_ID()` is easier to read, never mind that many such metadata functions don't obey isolation level semantics (meaning they can block even if you've set read_uncommitted or snapshot).